# mathematical symbol, what does the open circle mean?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation, function-and-relation-composition

What does the circle in d) and e) means?

In this exercise, I have to find inverse matrix.
$h:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is given by $$h(x,y,z) = (4x+y,x+z,-2x+3y+z)$$

(d) $g \circ h$

(e) $h \circ g$

Comment: $(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$

Comment: composition of functions

Comment: You don't include a definition for $g(x, y, z)$, so the composition of $g(h(x))$ and $h(g(x))$  cannot be determined.

Comment: As for finding the inverse matrix for $h$, that has nothing to do with the question asked in the title as to the meaning of $\circ$.  In any event, you should know how to find the matrix representation of $h$ and then you should know how to invert matrices.  It should all be routine.  Check your book or notes for related examples.

Answer (score 1):

It means composition,  for Instance $g(x)=x^2$ and $f(x)=-1/x$.
So $g(f(x)) = (-1/x)^2 = \frac{1}{x^2}$ and $f(g(x))= \frac{-1}{x^2}$

Comment: This should have been a comment. You fail to notice address the fact that as written, the OP cannot compose anything. As g(x) is not defined in the OP.